# How can I categoriese / classify a cluster of words?

Tags: classification, clustering, text-mining, nlp, lda

I am just wondering if it is possible to classify word clusters?

For example if I provide you an array of words `[bird,chicken,dock,park,apple,grapes,furits,juice]` 
what I need is to convert this array to something like this (or nearest possible)

```
[
   "Birds"=>[bird,chicken,dock,park],
   "Fruits"=>[apple,grapes,furits,juice,park]
]
```

Any direction to how I can achieve this, please?

Comment: These are human concepts. So you need a *lot* of human input, this won't work unsupervised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic solution:**
You could convert the words to vectors, word2vec. If you can get trained word embeddings that would be a good starting point.

Then you need to cluster the vectors which should be straight forward, e.g using KMeans. What you are asking for is some hierarchy as well, which could be tricky to find with a clustering method, at least if it needs to make sense.

If you want the words closest to "Birds" you could try to just get words with the closes distance to "Bird" and test if that works out.

**If the hierarchy is important:** Then you likely need to use other techniques in NLP, which I am not experienced with. Have a look at "Entity linking" as an example.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this Carl